# How open and read JSON file?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have json file  but this file have weight 186 mb. I try read via python .

```
import json
f = open('file.json','r')
r = json.loads(f.read())

ValueError: Extra data: line 88 column 2 -...
```

[FILE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cYHuYG-rxty7jyUAu2AnKofJUQfN4ZN8)

How to open it? Help me

Comment: Your JSON file appears to be invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON file isn't a JSON file, it's several JSON files mashed together.

The first instance of this occurs in the 1630070th character:

```
'шова"}]}]}{"response":[{"count'
           ^ here
```

That said, [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) appears to be able to handle it, so the individual parts are fine.

You'll need to split the file at the boundaries of the individual JSON objects. Try catching the JSONDecodeError and use its `.colno` to slice the text into correct chunks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
r = json.loads(f)
```